# Apache Pulsar on Windows

Tags: apache-pulsar

I'm very new to Pulsar. Looking at the documentation about how to install a Standalone Pulsar system, I see the following sentence :

"Currently, Pulsar is available for 64-bit macOS, Linux, and Windows. To use Pulsar, you need to install 64-bit JRE/JDK 8 or later versions."

So Windows is supported. I downloaded the Pulsar binaries and unzip it to some location on my workstation.

But the /bin folder does not contain any Windows batch/executable. Only Unix shell script a provided.

My question is how do we start a Stand alone Pulsar on Windows as obviously the command "bin/pulsar standalone" does not work on Windows systems.

Thanks

Comment: there was a bug when running pulsar on window: ./pulsar: line 360: exec: C:\Program: not found

Answer (score 0):

You can run Pulsar on Docker or K8.   That is your best option for Windows.

you can try Windows with Linux subsystem.

I don't really recommend using the standalone Pulsar on Windows.

C# for Windows client is solid though.

Run a training environment free here https://www.academy.streamnative.io/